# How to clear a text file without deleting it using groovy

Tags: groovy

I've a text file which I'll be using it to write content.. But every time before I write something to the file, I wish to clear the content without deleting the file..

How would I achieve the above? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25):

With text files you can simply set it to an empty string.

```
file.text = ''
```

Comment: Everyone upvoted your helpful comment but no one bothered to actually upvote your answer! +1

Answer (score 6):

I would use [the `setBytes` method on `java.io.File`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#setBytes(byte[])) and provide it with an empty byte array:

```
file.bytes = new byte[0]
```

Passing an empty list also works, impressively.

```
file.bytes = []
```

Comment: Or, if you are working with text you can use `file.text = ''`

Comment: @cjstehno This should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want simply to overwrite the file with new content. To do that:

```
def content = ...

new File("test.txt").withWriter { writer ->
    writer.write(content)
}
```

Note that `File.withWriter` will do all the usual housekeeping re: open/close file.

Comment: I have been using "write" method..

Example:
'def file = new File("C:/Groovy.txt")
file.write("Hello")'

I wish to clear the content before writing the next set of content..

Comment: You don't have to use withWriter two times.  Just write the new content.

Comment: @UmeshKumar You are aware, that above code is something different than your code?  Also it would help for next time, that you add code, you already have tried to your questions, so others can build up from there.

Comment: My initial answer was based on a literal reading of the question. That is, (a) clear the file without deleting then (b) write content. I realize now that the request is surely to simply overwrite the file so I've updated the answer.