# Why does file.append write "hello world" as duplicate in csv file

Tags: groovy, soapui

When I run the following code:

```
f = new File(projectroot + "/outputTest1.csv")
f.append("hello world" + '\n')
```

Here is the result in csv file:

```
hello world
hello world
```

Why is it displaying a duplicate?

Take note: I'm using groovy in soapUI

Answer (score 1):

Append adds given string to the end of the file, so when you run it for the third time, it should display 3 hello worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible explanations there :

- You're not clearing the file content before writing to it, which means you'll add a new line with "Hello world" every time you execute your code. Either :

  - use the "[Write](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#write(java.lang.String))" method instead of "[Append](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#append(byte[]))"
  - clear the file using `file.bytes = new byte[0]`
- You call this piece of code twice, which can be checked by adding a log/display and checking if your log only appears once.

**Further reading :**

- [SO question about file clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549160/how-to-clear-a-text-file-without-deleting-it-using-groovy)
- [Groovy documentation about file handling](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-io.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was using this code inside of an assertion of SoapUI then created duplicate. When I added a separate groovy step with the same code then it worked correctly.